# Prove $10^{3n+1}+10^{6n+2}+1=111k$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm stuck to prove this one can anyone help me please?

> Prove that $10^{3n+1}+10^{6n+2}+1=111k$.

I'm not sure what exactly I should do.

n is a natural number and k is an integer

Comment: what does k imply in this question?

Comment: Did you try induction?

Comment: Since this is labeled elementary number theory, I would think that this is equivalent to showing $10^{n+1}+10^{6n+2}+1\equiv 0\pmod{111}$.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Nice catch Michael!

Comment: This is false for $n=1$.

Comment: Yea seems to work only for $n\equiv 0 \pmod{3}$ ..

Comment: for n = 0 , k = 1

Comment: can i prove it with (n+1) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OP has corrected the problem.  The corrected answer is below.

Assuming that $k$ must be an integer (not stated by OP), this is the same as showing that
$$
10^{n+1}+10^{6n+2}+1\equiv 0\pmod{111}.
$$
Observe that $10^3=1000=999+1=1+9(111)$.  Therefore, there are only three values for the first and second terms, $10$, $100$, and $1$.  In particular, when
$$
10^{n+1}=\begin{cases}10&n+1\equiv 1\pmod 3\\100&n+1\equiv 2\pmod 3\\1&n+1\equiv 0\pmod 3.\end{cases}=\begin{cases}10&n\equiv 0\pmod 3\\100&n\equiv 1\pmod 3\\1&n\equiv 2\pmod 3.\end{cases}
$$
On the other hand, there is only one value for $10^{6n+2}\pmod{111}$ since $10^{6n}=(10^3)^{2n}\equiv 1^{2n}=1\pmod{111}$.  Therefore, the second term is equivalent to $100$ modulo $111$.

This appears to be a problem, since (modulo $111$) there are exactly three sums $10+11+1$, $100+100+1$, and $1+100+1$, only the first one is equivalent to $0$ modulo $111$.  In other words, if we let $n=1$, then the sum is $100,000,101$, which is not a multiple of $111$.

To the OP, please check the original statement.  The statement would be correct if the first term were $10^{3n+1}$, however.

When the first term is $10^{3n+1}$ instead of $10^{n+1}$, observe that $10^{3n}=(10^3)^n\equiv 1^n=1\pmod{111}$, therefore, the sum can be reduced to
$$
10^{3n+1}+10^{6n+2}+1\equiv 10+10^2+1\equiv 0\pmod{111}.
$$

Comment: MICHEAL THE STATMENT IS 10^(3n+1) IM SO SORRY I MISSTYPED!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

There's a typo. The assertion should be
$$10^{3n+1}+10^{6n+2}+1\equiv 0\mod111.$$
As  $10^3\equiv1 \bmod 3$ and$\bmod37$, and $3$ and $37$ are coprime, $10^3\equiv 1\bmod 111$. Hence
$$10^{3n+1}+10^{6n+2}+1\equiv 10+10^2+1=111\equiv0\mod111.$$

Comment: I would have thought exactly like you in terms of $3$ and $37$, but perhaps it is also worth noting that $10^3 -1 = 999 = 9 \cdot 111$.

Comment: Sorry, but you've missed $10^{6n+2}$.

Comment: That's right, and I hesitated, but finally decided for a presentation in terms of $3$ and $37$, as it illustrates a more general procedure (splitting the modulus into smaller factors). With big numbers, usually  you won't do the division without serious reasons.

Comment: @Babak: Fixed. Thanks for pointing the typo!

Comment: @Bernard In your initial statement informing about the typo in OPs first presentation, followed by a "corrected" version, which needs to be edited from  $10^{3n+2}$ to $10^{6n+2}$.  I'm sure it's simply a typo, given your demonstration and conclusion.

Comment: @amWhy: Two typos in a single short answer… It's my day! Thanks for pointing it!

Comment: @AndreasCaranti Or,more generally, we can use $\,x^3\equiv 1\pmod{x^2+x+1},\,$ see my answer.

Comment: @BillDubuque, +1

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\ {\rm mod}\,\ i^2\!+i+1\!:\,\ \color{#0a0}{i^3}\equiv\color{#c00}{\bf 1}\ $ by $\ i^3\!-1 = (i\!-\!1)(i^2\!+i+1)\equiv 0\ $

therefore  $\qquad\quad  \begin{align} &\color{#0a0}i^{\large \color{#0a0}{3}j}\, i^{\large  2} + {\color{#0a0}i^{\large\color{#0a0}{3}k}}\, i +  1\\ 
\equiv\ &\,\color{#c00}{\bf 1}^{\large  j}\,i^{\large 2}\,  + \color{#c00}{\bf 1}^{\large  k}\, i + 1\\
\equiv\ &\quad\ i^{\large 2}\ \  +\,\ \ \ i+1\ \equiv\ 0 \end{align}\qquad $ OP is case $\,i = 10,\ j=2n,\ k=n$